# ngx-datatable not rendering properly

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I am trying to update a swimlane dataTable, I have a component with an input, the input value is used to show some values, then I have a list that a filter when the input changes, something like this:

```
   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      this.dataTableList = this.data.find(
        x => x.productId == this.inputValue.id
      );
  }
```

The `dataTableList` is used to fill the datatable, the filter is working, and the table is render properly on first load, but when I change the input, the table changes but does not render properly, I mean it shows like this:
[image]
On first load it shows like this (see the total count changes):
[image]

It's only render properly when i have the component is destroyed and build again, i tried using custom `detectChanges()` method of [Angular's ChangeDetectorRef class](https://docs.angular.lat/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)but still the same problem, any ideas?